# RestSharp - Ignore SSL errors WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any whay that I can get RestSharp to ignore errors in SSL certificates on Windows phone 8? I have a test client, and the service I connect to does not yet have a valid cetificate.

When I make a request now I get the error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust 
relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Thanks in advance